# Why did Shift+F3 stop working in Notepad++?

Tags: search, notepad++

<kbd>F3</kbd> (find next) and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (find previous) work in many other editors. <kbd>F3</kbd> continues to work in version 7.8.9, but <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> stopped working: it just does nothing.

I don't know what was the last version I had where <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> worked for me.

Comment: No one uses that, and my favorite kind of optimization is removing stuff.

Comment: Shift+F3 works for me in v7.8.9.

Comment: Try Ctrl + Shift + F3

Comment: Reverse searching for a Regex has been disabled because of problems in some cases. See item 10 in the [7.8.7 Release notes](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v7.8.7/). See also [this forum topic](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/19848/find-previous-shortcut-not-working). I believe that the Notepad++ forum has had a longer discussion of the topic, but I cannot find it now.

Comment: Thanks for the responses!  I just realized it only stopped working for regular expressions.  If I ensure my search mode is "Normal", it continues to work.  I also was able to edit the config.xml file and get the full functionality back.  Thanks again!

Comment: The config.xml change is to add "regexBackward4PowerUser"="yes" to <FindHistory...

Comment: @niofis an excellent demonstration of the principle "if I haven't thought of [a need for] it, it then it doesn't exist". Akin to [NIH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here). Akin to [object permanence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_permanence).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The comments explain it, so here's a summary. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> works (v7.9.5) if you last searched with Normal or Extended mode. It doesn't work if the last search was with Regular expression mode.

The reason, to quote AdrianHHH, is:

> Reverse searching for a Regex has been disabled because of problems in some cases. See item 10 in the [7.8.7 Release notes](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v7.8.7/). See also [this forum topic](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/19848/find-previous-shortcut-not-working). I believe that the Notepad++ forum has had a longer discussion of the topic, but I cannot find it now.

Comment: this is inconvenient, but I can see why they did it